# Error while altering js file Undefined index: scope in drupal_get_js() (line 4309

Tags: hooks, javascript

I need to change javascript code of jCarousel, and I want to create my own function and change it in `hook_js_alter()`, but it is not working properly, or I missing something.

```
function common_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if ($node->type == 'home') {
      if (array_key_exists('sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js', $javascript)) {
        $file = drupal_get_path('module', 'common') . '/js/jcarousel.js';
        $javascript['sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js'] = drupal_js_defaults($file);
        dpm($javascript);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to change `sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js` to `drupal_get_path('module', 'common') . '/js/jcarousel.js'`. The path is correct, but as I can see with `dpm()` no scope is enabled and type.

Comment: You should just change `$javascript['sites/all/libraries/jquery.jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.js']['data']`, not all the other values.

Comment: i tried, but its not working, and i got an error `Undefined index: scope in drupal_get_js() `

Comment: Then something else is wrong, but not in that code. [drupal_js_defaults()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_js_defaults/7) surely sets `'scope'`.

Answer (score 3):

Just got into this function too to alter "folder/js_file.js" and the issue causing the

> Notice: Undefined index: scope in drupal_get_js() (line 4309 of
>   [DRUPAL_DIR]\includes\common.inc).

error is that there are times when the hook is called but "folder/js_file.js" is not yet in the array w/c just adds

```
[folder/js_file.js] => Array(
  [data] => [your_custom_js],
)
```

to the array but the scope, type, and other attributes are not there. So we first need to check if the array key exists like so:

```
if (isset($javascript['folder/js_file.js'])) {
  $file = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/your_custom_js.js';
  $javascript['folder/js_file.js']['data'] = $file;
}
```

That solves it. :)

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work at all.

Comment: While using  drupal_js_defaults() as sugested in comments to question gives me bunch of other errors, this works great.